# Changed sources.list, but still updates from archive.raspberrypi.org

Tags: apt

i am using a local apt-mirror to mirror raspbian and ubuntu and changed to `/etc/apt/sources.list` on my pi. But it still updates from archive.raspberrypi.org.

From apt-mirror config:

```
#Raspbian
deb-armhf http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian jessie main contrib non-free rpi
```

`apt-get update` output:

```
Hit http://<IP-of-my-ubuntu-server> jessie InRelease
Get:1 http://archive.raspberrypi.org jessie InRelease [13.2 kB]
Get:2 http://<IP-of-my-ubuntu-server> jessie/main armhf Packages [8,964 kB]
Get:3 http://archive.raspberrypi.org jessie/main armhf Packages [144 kB]
Get:4 http://archive.raspberrypi.org jessie/ui armhf Packages [8,311 B]
Ign http://archive.raspberrypi.org jessie/main Translation-en_GB
Ign http://archive.raspberrypi.org jessie/main Translation-en
Ign http://archive.raspberrypi.org jessie/ui Translation-en_GB
Ign http://archive.raspberrypi.org jessie/ui Translation-en
Get:5 http://<IP-of-my-ubuntu-server> jessie/contrib armhf Packages [37.5 kB]
Get:6 http://<IP-of-my-ubuntu-server> jessie/non-free armhf Packages [70.3 kB]
Get:7 http://<IP-of-my-ubuntu-server> jessie/rpi armhf Packages [1,356 B]
Ign http://<IP-of-my-ubuntu-server> jessie/contrib Translation-en_GB
Ign http://<IP-of-my-ubuntu-server> jessie/contrib Translation-en
Ign http://<IP-of-my-ubuntu-server> jessie/main Translation-en_GB
Ign http://<IP-of-my-ubuntu-server> jessie/main Translation-en
Ign http://<IP-of-my-ubuntu-server> jessie/non-free Translation-en_GB
Ign http://<IP-of-my-ubuntu-server> jessie/non-free Translation-en
Ign http://<IP-of-my-ubuntu-server> jessie/rpi Translation-en_GB
Ign http://<IP-of-my-ubuntu-server> jessie/rpi Translation-en
Fetched 9,238 kB in 25s (365 kB/s)
Reading package lists... Done
```

Comment: Are there entries in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ ?

Comment: @joan yes, there is: deb http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian/ jessie main ui

Comment: Can I just add this archive to my apt-mirror and change it to the ip of my server?

Comment: I suppose.  Why not just comment it out if you don't use anything within the repository?  It'll be Foundation tailored packages for the Pi, e.g. gpiozero, Wolfram, RPi.GPIO, wiringPi etc.

Comment: @joan maybe I need something from that repository

Comment: Only you can know that.  You could browse the repository to see its contents.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm having the same exact same problem right now, 8 months after this question is asked. But I have found a solution for this, and I manage to successfully install PIXEL desktop environment on my RetroPie in a matter of minutes.

First, edit the **raspi.list** file :

```
nano /etc/apt/sources.list.d/raspi.list
```

Comment out all the existing lines (including the archive.raspberrypi.org of course). Then add the following line :

```
deb http://mirrors.ustc.edu.cn/archive.raspberrypi.org/debian/ jessie main ui
```

Save the file, then execute `apt-get update` and continue what you intended to do. I hope this helps answer other complaints about how slow the speed of raspberry pi debian archive server is.

Answer (score 0):

This one that worked for me, remove debian/ from what Hendri Winarto suggested.

```
deb http://mirrors.ustc.edu.cn/archive.raspberrypi.org/ jessie main ui
```

Answer (score 0):

In Debian Buster, you need to modify two files to change the archive address. Just delete everything in these two files and add in the text below:

1. /etc/apt/sources.list

```
deb http://mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/raspbian/raspbian/ buster main non-free contrib rpi
deb-src http://mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/raspbian/raspbian/ buster main non-free contrib rpi
```

2. /etc/apt/sources.list.d/raspi.list

```
deb http://mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/raspberrypi/ buster main ui
```

Note: I showed the [Tsinghua University mirror](https://mirror.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/help/raspbian/) here. For other options best-suited for your location, see this [official list](https://www.raspbian.org/RaspbianMirrors).